# I need assistance with my IP Logger

Tags: php, file, logging, directory

I need help with my IP logger.

### at my index.php file, I use this code:

---->  $line = date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "                                                     - $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]";
file_put_contents('cpanel/iphenter.log', $line . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

And in my cpanel directory, I have a home.php file. In this home.php file I use the following code to implement the .log file in a DIV:

--->  include 'iphenter.log' ;

At this point, everything works. But, every IP mashes 'crashes' together(Not sure how to explain this properly).

So, here is my question: How do I make a IP go on their own line.  doesnt work in a PHP code, so how do I make it 'press enter' after every log?

I hope you understood my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $line = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+2 hours")) . " - " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."<br \>";
```

Is the output generated to HTML or a text file? If it is a text file, you can try:

```
 $line = date('Y-m-d H:i:s' , strtotime("+2 hours") ) . " - " $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n";
```

Comment: The concept of using a <br /> works, but the problem is that the linechange is at the wrong spot. I want the <br /> to be at the end, so the next IP goes on the next line, if that gives any sense.

Comment: One issue left.. How do I edit the time zone? My clock is 2 hours in front of this code..

Comment: Use strtotime() in your date function and add 2 hours

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? REALLY new in PHP.. thanks

Comment: Well, the +2 hours doesnt work. Its only +1 hour, i've even tried +3 hours but it still doesnt work :P